# Hide this OpenMPI message

Tags: openmpi

Anytime I run an MPI program with "mpirun -n 1 myprogram" I get this message:

Reported: 1 (out of 1) daemons - 1 (out of 1) procs

How do I disable this message? I am using Open MPI 1.6.5

Comment: How do you compile your `myprogram`? Are you using a flag that might cause your program to be more verbose? Probably, while configuring your OpenMPI, you set some flag to true/on, which gives you this verbose output. I'd suggest that you check your config.log to understand this issue further. Alternatively, you can install a newer version of OpenMPI, which I'd highly recommend. You shouldn't see any such messages each time you run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the value of the `orte_report_launch_progress` MCA parameter is set to true. This could either be coming from the system-wide Open MPI configuration file or from an environment variable named `OMPI_MCA_orte_report_launch_progress`. In any case, you may override it by passing `--mca orte_report_launch_progress 0` to `mpirun`:

```
mpirun --mca orte_report_launch_progress 0 -n 1 myprogram
```

If the value is coming from the system-wide Open MPI configuration, you may also override it by appending the following to `$HOME/.openmpi/mca-params.conf` (create the file /and the directory/ if it doesn't exist):

```
orte_report_launch_progress = 0
```

Comment: Ah yes! That's what I was looking for. Setting "export OMPI_MCA_orte_report_launch_progress=0" in my .bashrc did the trick